# disable text selection and add exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onmousedown, onselect

if i use this style for the `<body>`

```
onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'
```

is it possible to give the exceptions by using javascript for inputs textareas and selects?
and if yes then can u show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can disable text selection without needing heavy-handed JavaScript event handlers. See my answer here: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620)

Summary: use CSS and the `unselectable` expando in IE.

CSS:

```
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" unselectable="on" class="unselectable">...</div>
```

Comment: ok it will turn off the selection of text but how do i select inputs textareas and select buttons?

Comment: Doing this still allows you to select text within inputs and textareas.

Comment: yeah yeah ) i've tested it, but it doesnt work in Opera... :(

Comment: Really? Works fine for me in Opera. Have you got a test page I can see?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent [**event bubbling**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) for textboxes and selects.

You can use [**`:input`**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector to select all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Something like

```
$(":input").bind("mousedown", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7Qmq/1/)

Comment: but u blocked the body content by using javascript, i wanted to block by using css, and add exceptions by javascript