# Disable text selection in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I need to find a way to prevent users from selecting text in a textarea.
The goal is to create a custom keyboard that is used to enter text in the textarea. I want users to be able to click on the textarea to set the caret position (which is already working right now). However, I don't want the users to be able to select certain parts of the inserted text, or there should at least be no visual indication of this.
I have already tried a few things, such as the following CSS, but without success.

```
textarea {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The solution can be in CSS and/or JavaScript, and it only has to work in Google Chrome.

---

Disabling the textarea will not work for me. As I mentioned, I want users to be able to place the caret at certain positions by clicking on the location. If I would disable the textarea, this functionality would be lost.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, wouldn't disabled do what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712030/disable-text-selection-and-add-exceptions

Comment: Disabling the text selection is easy...  you're really asking how to disable text selection while still allowing users to click to place the cursor at a specific point?

Comment: Disabling the element will also prevent any keyboard actions from getting through, so that is probably not a good solution.

Comment: @BramW. well the answer by OPUS *almost* works; it's possible to navigate through the textarea content with arrow keys, but it's not possible to click in the content.  Disabling selection I suppose also disables that (which seems wrong, but what can you do).

Answer (score 9):

A combination of the "readonly" property and "user-select" property works.

The 2nd rule disables the highlighted border on select, which is a kind of visual selection.

The "unselectable" property seems to be Opera/IE specific.

the styles:

```
.noselect {
   cursor: default;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
}

.noselect:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

the markup:

```
<textarea class="noselect" readonly="readonly" unselectable="on"></textarea>
```

read-only might be more suitable than disabled (one can still toggle with JS, upon click event).

Comment: @Gorky for reference: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/tags/removals  ...if something had changed, it should be listed there (I'm in a hurry right now, no time to dig further).

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=881308&can=1&q=user-select%3A%20none%20input&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified Looks like intentional for interop

Answer (score 4):

```
<textarea unselectable="on" id="my_textarea"></textarea>

    *.unselectable {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: Has no effect in Firefox.

Comment: thats because user wants it only in chrome.We can add moz-user-select:none

Comment: oops sorry, I missed that, and you're also right that `-moz-user-select: none` works! I think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can help you

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtInput').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. Here's one of my own:

```css
textarea::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: this is not correct solution what if someone copy text without knowing he selected the text

Comment: My purpose was only to hide the highlight. If you want to disable the text selection, `user-select: none;` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just put disabled="disabled" in textarea, like this :

`<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>`

Comment: I tried just putting <textarea disabled></textarea> as w3schools and other suggest. This answer was the only way I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answers didn't work for me, so I put a div with `position: absolute;` on top of the textarea, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable it with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").disable='true';
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<textarea disabled="readonly"></textarea>
```

tested it is working.

Comment: The OP does not want to make the textarea read-only, he would just want the select functionality to be disabled.

Comment: by disabling the textarea, text selection can be done

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka disabling the element will prevent keyboard events from being generated, so that probably won't work for the OP.