# Svg: Does user-select property not work in the foreignobject element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have below html fragment:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div 
      style="position: absolute; width: 953px; height: 725.57px; transform-origin: left top; z-index: 90; touch-action: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="953" height="725.5699020480855" viewBox="0 0 1123 855" style="pointer-events: auto; cursor: crosshair;">
        <g>
          <g id="1f6020e0-f101-419a-8f2c-74069caebad9">
            <foreignObject x="528.9701559220881" y="173.25467684286463" width="200" height="80">
              <textarea style="border: none;outline: none;background: transparent;resize: inherit;overflow: hidden;color: rgb(255, 0, 0);font-family: Helvetica;overflow-wrap: break-word;width: 200px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 18.4px;cursor: crosshair;pointer-events: none;height: 40px;user-select: none;">s123456789</textarea>
            </foreignObject>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I don't want is the ***textarea*** element defined in the ***foreignObject*** element can be selected like below[image: text selected]

I have added `user-select: none` in the style definition, but it doesn't work, I am not sure whether it's because the `user-select` property is not working under the ***foreignObject*** element, can anybody help to explain ?

Comment: Doesn't seem selectable to me.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138669/disable-text-selection-in-textarea

Comment: It's a Chrome bug, works in Firefox